# Change elevated button color via radio buttons in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, colors, radio-button

I want to change the Elevated button color when I press the radio buttons. 1.button -> red, 2.button -> yellow, 3.button -> green. In the Elevated.stylefrom if condition did not work. Just ternary condition works but it is only for one condition. I want to add 3 conditions. I hope it was clear.

Or do I need to create a model for this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:task_shopping_app/const/const.dart';
import 'package:task_shopping_app/screens/city_input_screen.dart';
import 'package:task_shopping_app/screens/weather.dart';

class RadioButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RadioButtonState createState() => _RadioButtonState();
}

class _RadioButtonState extends State<RadioButton> {
  int selectedValue = 0;
  final enteredCityInfo = TextEditingController();
  String name = '';
  // if selectedValue and group value matches then radio button will be selected.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          ButtonBar(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Radio<int>(
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: selectedValue,
                  onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                        selectedValue = value!;
                        print(selectedValue);
                      })),
              Radio<int>(
                  value: 2,
                  groupValue: selectedValue,
                  onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                        selectedValue = value!;
                        print(selectedValue);
                      })),
              Radio<int>(
                  value: 3,
                  groupValue: selectedValue,
                  onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                        selectedValue = value!;
                        print(selectedValue);
                      })),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: enteredCityInfo,
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                name = enteredCityInfo.text;
                //Here we want to see user entry for the text field area in the debug console.
                print(name);
                // Get.to(() => WeatherScreen());
              });
            },
            child: Text('Create'),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: selectedValue == 1 ? Colors.red : Colors.yellow,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a function to convert the value into `Color`s

```dart
Color valueToColor(int value) {
  switch (value) {
    case 1:
      return Colors.red;
    case 2:
      return Colors.yellow;
    case 3:
      return Colors.green;
    default:
      /// return whatever you like to deal with some exceptional case
  }
}
```

And make the `style` parameter of `ElevatedButton` like following

```dart
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: valueToColor(selectedValue),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this for multiple conditions:

```
primary:(selectedValue == 1) ? Colors.red : (selectedValue == 2)? 
Colors.yellow:Colors.green,
```